# Gradient paints not working in Apache Batik's svggen

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, batik

I am using Apache Batik's SVGGraphics2D class to bridge my swing drawing calls to SVG. 
It works fine with the exception that LinearGradientPaint elements are ignored completely. 
The [setup code is taken from the svggen tutorial](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/svg-generator.html) and as simple as it can be.

The svg-file reports "fill:none". Is there something that I am missing or is this a bug?
The code uses Batik ver. 1.7 on JRE 1.6 Swing classes.

Comment: Did you set up the ExtensionHandler, as described in the referenced page? It would be good, if you posted a simple, working example for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, as lbalazscs noted, the extension handler. I did not find a proper implementation of the svggen ExtensionHandler on the web, so I wrote one myself.

The code processes LinearGradientPaint and RadialGradientPaint (feel free to add more)

https://gist.github.com/4509119

The snippet has also been reported on Batik's issue tracker:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BATIK-1032

Comment: There is now an unofficial wrapper that deals with that problem, so you don't have to do it yourself: https://github.com/javagl/SvgGraphics